# How does a C# runspace/pipeline execute a powershell script?

Tags: c#, powershell

There are so many questions and answers about *how* to execute a powershell script from C# code, but I would like to know how exactly the runspace/pipeline *performs the execution* of the .ps1 file.

The context in which I am asking is this:
I've built a basic asp.net front end for a powershell script that sets up a new website. It creates the site in IIS and sets up wwwroot folders, log folders, an AD user and everything else that it needs. It works perfectly when I run it as an admin in powershell. However, when I run it through my C# pipeline, it breaks the pipe with a parameter binding exception.

*I'm not after an answer to this specific problem*, I'm just looking for an explanation of how the pipeline executes my file so that I can have a better understanding of what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a complete explanation of how the runspace works, but I've [written a blog post](http://harrietgl.wordpress.com/2013/09/13/how-to-runspace-part-1/) covering the main bits.

Also a snippet from [one of the msdn pages on how powershell works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714658%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> The Powershell runtime is invoked as a runspace and will, by default,
>   process commands synchronously and deliver the results of processing
>   to the host application so that they can be returned to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [ILSpy](http://www.ilspy.net) or opening the class in **Class View** to see the code for the class? I do this all the time to see how Microsoft implements a particular class. I would paste the code here if it was a short answer, but there is a lot to the System.Management.Automation.Runspaces or Microsoft.Powershell namespaces. Take a look for yourself, and you will be able to see exactly how Microsoft implements the execution of Powershell scripts.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I gave this a go but it didn't provide any extra information on how the file gets executed. Most of the methods were along these lines: 
    `public Collection<PSObject> Invoke()
    {
       using (Pipeline._trace.TraceMethod())
       return this.Invoke((IEnumerable) null);
    }
    public abstract Collection<PSObject> Invoke(IEnumerable input);`